# Dropbox sometimes generates a boot failure of the EXT4 partition on Ubuntu

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, ext4

Dropbox sometimes generates a mounting failure of an ext4 partition while booting the Ubuntu desktop PC. At that time, the log message was as follows:

```
 ...... Omission ......
ata2.00: status: (D32F ER3 )
ats2.00: error: ( UNC )
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2738954872
Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 342369103, async page read.
```

[image]

End of line

BRs,
Geunsik Lim.

Comment: In this case, Systemd (init process) of Ubuntu distribution displays the below message on display.

Welcome to emergency model After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): ___

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about programming, and thus seems to be off topic (i.e. not software you are writing or debugging). A Ubuntu forum or stack exchange site would be more appropriate place for this kind of question.

Comment: I do not think so. It is generated by a limited operation of software such as ext4's  extent attribute and sync mechanism of Dropbox utility. So, this issue is an appropriate content at the stackoverflow website.

Comment: Stack overflow is for questions about *programming*, not how to use software, not how to fix your ubuntu dropbox issue (unless you are a dropbox developer and you ask a question about programming, generally showing a minimal but complete example of code!). Please read about [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." (this does not)

Answer (score -1):

I figure out a recipe to fix this issue.

```
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): __  <--- Type root password. 
ubuntu# fsck -fy /dev/sdb1 [enter]
.... Waiting for some minutes
ubuntu#
ubuntu#
```

I could boot the Ubuntu PC again after executing manually  "fsck" command  using -f flag. But, I am not sure why Dropbox folder results in the mounting failure of the /dev/sdb1 (ext4) partition. BTW, I could not find any similar articles at StackOverflow. Welcome to any hint and similar experience. :)